# classic asp create xml attribute repeats on second tag

Tags: xml, asp-classic, attributes, xmldocument, xml-documentation

using the next code to create a simple xml document in classic asp:

```
dim xmlDoc: set xmlDoc = server.createobject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
dim objRoot,objRecord,objAttribute,objIntro,objChild
dim newFileName: newFileName = "testing"
strFolder = server.mappath("/")

set objRoot = xmlDoc.createElement("Document")
set objAttribute = xmlDoc.createAttribute("xmlns")
objAttribute.nodeValue = "urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.008.001.02"
objRoot.setAttributeNode(objAttribute)
xmlDoc.appendChild objRoot

set objRecord = xmlDoc.createElement("Level1-1")
objRoot.appendChild objRecord

set objRecord = xmlDoc.createElement("Level1-2")
objRoot.appendChild objRecord

set objRecord = xmlDoc.createElement("Level1-3")
set objChild = xmlDoc.createElement("Level1-3-1")
objChild.text = "Level1-3-1"
objRecord.appendChild objChild

objRoot.appendChild objRecord

Set objIntro = xmlDoc.createProcessingInstruction("xml","version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'")  
xmlDoc.insertBefore objIntro,xmlDoc.childNodes(0)  
xmlDoc.save (strFolder & "\userdata\file\" & newFileName & ".xml")
response.write "<a href=""/userdata/file/" & newFileName & ".xml"" target=""_blank"">Open XML</a>"
set xmlDoc = nothing
```

This give the next result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.008.001.02">
    <Level1-1 xmlns=""/>
    <Level1-2 xmlns=""/>
    <Level1-3 xmlns="">
        <Level1-3-1>Level1-3-1</Level1-3-1>
    </Level1-3>
</Document>
```

As you can see the atrribute that was created on the root element Document is repeated in every tag on the second level. Although it was not created in the code. At the third level (Level1-3-1) there is no attribute.

Anyone any idea why this is happening? And how to avoid this?

thanks Walther

Answer (score 1):

You can use [setAttribute Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms754616(v%3Dvs.85)) to add the attribute and its value to that specific element.

```
objRoot.setAttribute "xmlns","urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.008.001.02"
```